# onResume update view from recyclerview adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

i have some problems with updating fragment view after item deleted. So i have one fragment which one showing all items added from another activity. And when im trying to delete item it's not updating view so i should restart fragment to see updated fragment.

There is my fragment

```
public class MyGarageFragment extends Fragment {

    FloatingActionButton fab;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    RVAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_garage, null);


        mRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());

        showRecord();

        fab = v.findViewById(R.id.addFabButton);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//                startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), AddRecordActivity.class));
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AddAutoActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("editMode",false);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        return v;
    }

    private void showRecord() {
        adapter = new RVAdapter(getContext(),databaseHelper.getAllData(Constants.C_ADD_TIMESTAMP + " DESC"));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        showRecord();
        
    }
```

also my Recyclerview Adapter

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.Holder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Model> arrayList;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_my_garage,parent,false);

        return new Holder(view);
    }

    public RVAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Holder holder, int position) {

        Model model = arrayList.get(position);
        String id = model.getId();
        String image = model.getImage();
        String name = model.getName();
        String age = model.getAge();
        String phone = model.getPhone();
        String addTimeStamp = model.getAddTimeStamp();
        String updateTimeStamp = model.getUpdateTimeStamp();

        holder.profileIv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(image));
        holder.name.setText(name);
        holder.age.setText(age);
        holder.phone.setText(phone);

        holder.editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, holder.editButton);
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.action_edit:
                                editDialog(
                                        ""+position,
                                        ""+id,
                                        ""+name,
                                        ""+age,
                                        ""+phone,
                                        ""+image,
                                        ""+addTimeStamp,
                                        ""+updateTimeStamp
                                );
                                break;
                            case R.id.action_delete:
                                deleteDialog(""+id);
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                });
                popupMenu.show();
            }
        });


        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"item " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }

    private void deleteDialog(String id) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Delete");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure?");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_delete_24);

        builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                databaseHelper.deleteInfo(id);

                ((MyGarageFragment)context).onResume();


                Toast.makeText(context, "Delete Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
    }

    private void editDialog(String position, String id, String name, String age, String phone, String image, String addTimeStamp, String updateTimeStamp) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, EditAutoActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("ID",id);
        intent.putExtra("NAME",name);
        intent.putExtra("AGE",age);
        intent.putExtra("PHONE",phone);
        intent.putExtra("IMAGE",image);
        intent.putExtra("ADD_TIMESTAMP",addTimeStamp);
        intent.putExtra("UPDATE_TIMESTAMP",updateTimeStamp);
        intent.putExtra("editMode",true);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView profileIv;
        TextView name,age,phone;
        ImageView editButton;




        public Holder (@NonNull View itemView){
            super(itemView);


            profileIv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileIv);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            age = itemView.findViewById(R.id.age);
            phone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
            editButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editBtn);
        }
    }

}
```

so what should i do in deleteDialog to delete cardview item and refresh ui?

```
private void deleteDialog(String id) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle("Delete");
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure?");
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_delete_24);
    
            builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    databaseHelper.deleteInfo(id);
    
                    ((MyGarageFragment)context).onResume();
    
    
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Delete Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
    
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.create().show();
        }
```

Comment: Why are you starting an activity from your adapter? Are you aware of [notifyDataSetChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged())? There are also other various methods

Comment: yes but how to implement notifyDataSetChanged in this situation?

Comment: Once you delete an item from your database and change your recyclerview data, you can call it.